# Using FlatBuffers in React Native

Tags: react-native, flatbuffers

I'm trying to use FlatBuffers in a React Native project.

When I try to create a ByteBuffer object I'm getting this error.

```
Property 'TextDecoder' doesn't exist
```

Does FlatBuffers support React Native? It looks like a separate package would be required to support `TextDecoder` in React Native.

Comment: There is no direct support for React in flatbuffers. We do have a TS/JS implementation and it looks like react is in that language.

Comment: The problem we are having there is that is relies on TextDecoder which isn't available in React.